# How to find intersecting area of two polylines in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, area

I have two areas (let's say two polylines). I want to find the intersecting area between both using C++. The polylines are defined as a list of points (QVector). Do you have any clues for that?

If we have as input two polylines, the output should be another polyline with the intersecting area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
QVector<QPoint> intersection(const QVector<QPoint> &lhs, 
                             const QVector<QPoint> &rhs) {

    return QPolygon(lhs).intersected(rhs);
}
```

`QPolygon` inherits from `QVector<QPoint>`, and also has a constructor that accepts `QVector<QPoint>`.